# LINQ to SQL "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Child_Parent""

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm getting that SqlException while trying to insert data into a table using navigation property. Seems like the foreign key is not updated automatically and has a default value 0. The same time it works with auto-generated classes. I don't want to use auto-generated models.

How do I have to modify my models to make it work? Is it about INotifyPropertyChanging or INotifyPropertyChanged?

Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new DbContext();
        var p = db.Parents.Single(x => x.Id == 2);
        p.Children.Add(new Child_ { Name = "P2_Child_1" });
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}


class DbContext : DataContext
{
    public DbContext() : base(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True;") { }
    public Table<Parent_> Parents { get { return GetTable<Parent_>(); } }
    public Table<Child_> Children { get { return GetTable<Child_>(); } }
}

[Table(Name = "Parents")]
class Parent_
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association(OtherKey = "ParentId")]
    public EntitySet<Child_> Children { get; set; }

}

[Table(Name = "Children")]
class Child_
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, ThisKey = "ParentId", OtherKey = "Id")]
    public Parent_ Parent { get; set ; }
}
```

Comment: Your classes have to match the database in SQL Server.  So start by opening the data base with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server. Using the explorer in SSMS verify the keys in the database.  Then correct your classes to match the server.

Comment: @jdweng What does "verify" mean? I can get data from a DB using my models, I can get a collection of Children connected to a Parent but can't save a Parent with a new Child.

Comment: If you connect to DB with SSMS.  Using explorer you can locate the DB and Tables.  Then look at columns and keys.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to manually code the Insert method on an inherited DataContext:

```
Public Class ClientDataContext : Inherits DataContext

...

Public Sub InsertYourEntity(instance As YourEntity)
    With instance
        ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance)
        If TypeOf instance Is YourEntity then
            For each child As YourChildEntity In instance.YourChildEntities
                child.YourForeignKeyId = .Id
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

LinqToSql appears to use this method via reflection. So once coded resharper doesn't think its used, but integration tests hit it.